# How to get a count of number of WebElements

Tags: java, selenium

Is there a way to be able to find elements via WebElement and not using By?

Reason is that I want to find all the elements for 'testElement' but I am unsure how to code it as it is expecting a By and not WebElement. I am hoping there is a way via WebElement.

Example code below:

```
@FindBy(id = "test")
public WebElement testElement;
```

To get the size I would try the below but it fails as it expects a By:

```
List<WebElement> testCount = driver().findElements(elementPage.testElement);
        Assert.assertEquals(testCount.size(), 5);
```

Comment: What is `elementPage` ?

Comment: I thinks it's a pageObject

Comment: Yeah it's a pageObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're declaring it as a single webelement,
you should declare it as a list, like this:

```
@FindBy(id = "test")
public List<WebElement> testElement;
```

then you can use it in your code like this:

```
Assert.assertEquals(elementPage.testElement.size(), 5);
```

you can also try it directly, without the elementPage:

```
List<WebElement> testElement= driver.findElements(By.id("Test"));

System.out.println("Element count: " + testElement.size());
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Valga, no this doesn't work as it doesn't recognise .size()

Comment: strange, list.size() should be recognized, as it is a default method https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~wolber/courses/110/lectures/lists_in_java, did you change the variable type to List<WebElement>?

Comment: Oh no sorry I missed that, you declared it as a list